# How to change working directory in self-hosted runner?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a self hosted runner fully configured and working fine. But there's one simple issue, my working directory is `/var/www/repo_name` while the workflow clones inside my repo folder like this `/var/www/repo_name/repo_name`. When I use `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` it returns `/var/www`, which is correct and that's what I have set during the configuration. I have also tried adding:

```
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: /var/www/repo_name
```

but still no luck. Is there any way I can point it to the correct repo folder on my server?

Comment: the setting `defaults.run.working-directory` is only the working directory for `run` steps and does not influence `uses` steps etc.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: @BillDagg no :(